# Проблема с photos.saveWallPhoto

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, kohana

Возникла проблема при сохранении фотографии после загрузки. (пишу на фрэймворке `kohana`)
Как и написано в документации, сначала получаю адрес сервера для загрузки фото.

```
$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?group_id=$t&access_token=".$this->tokens['vkToken'];
    $data = json_decode(Request::factory($url)->execute()->body());
```

Далее загружаю само изображение на полученный адрес

```
$uploadData = array("photo" => '@'.APPPATH.'temp/imgs/'.basename($this->media->data->images->standard_resolution->url));
$res = Request::factory($data->response->upload_url)
        ->body($uploadData)
        ->method('POST')    
        ->execute()
        ->body();
$res = json_decode($res);
```

После чего пытаюсь сохранить загруженное изображение

```
        $data = Request::factory('https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto')
            ->query('server',$res->server)
            ->query('hash',$res->hash)
            ->query('photo',$res->photo)
            ->query('group_id',$to)
            ->query('access_token',$this->tokens['vkToken'])
            ->query('v','5.0')
            ->execute()->body();
    $data= json_decode($data);
```

Но сервер возвращает ошибку

```
    object(stdClass)#49 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#50 (3) {
    ["error_code"]=>
    int(121)
    ["error_msg"]=>
    string(12) "Invalid hash"
    ["request_params"]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#53 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(5) "oauth"
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#57 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(6) "method"
        ["value"]=>
        string(20) "photos.saveWallPhoto"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#55 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(6) "server"
        ["value"]=>
        string(6) "417017"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#51 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(4) "hash"
        ["value"]=>
        string(32) "d522051a8124f928175ad58..."
      }
      [4]=>
      object(stdClass)#52 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(5) "photo"
        ["value"]=>
        string(451) "Параметры фото..."
      }
      [5]=>
      object(stdClass)#48 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(8) "group_id"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "37398085"
      }
      [6]=>
      object(stdClass)#58 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(12) "access_token"
        ["value"]=>
        string(85) "Токен"
      }
      [7]=>
      object(stdClass)#56 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(1) "v"
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "5.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Я понимаю что сервер ругается на хэш, но я отдаю тот хэш который получил.
Может кто поможет? 
ps в багтрекер отписал, но все тихо и кто знает когда они ответят((

Answer (score 2):

Собственно проблема оказалась не в записи на стену, а в получении адреса сервера.
По привычке передал для получения gid отрицательный, но при этом запись на стену выдаёт ошибку на отрицательный gid, а я протупил и забыл, что в итоге у меня для "оборота" теперь два разный gid-а: с минусом и без. Убрав минус в параметрах получения адреса сервера загрузки я решил проблемы ушибки 121